# Logged into docker hub, but cannot pull Oracle Instant Client image

Tags: oracle, docker, dockerhub, oracleclient, instantclient

I have this in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM oracle/instantclient:12.2.0.1
```

when I tried to build I get:

```
Step 3/26 : FROM oracle/instantclient:12.2.0.1
pull access denied for oracle/instantclient, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

I thought this image was public on Docker hub? I am logged into docker hub, using `docker login --username=myself`

Here is the Docker Hub account:
https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-instant-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so first step I think you need to go and sign the user agreement on docker hub. The next step seems to be that it's:

```
FROM store/oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1
```

*not* this:

```
FROM oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is not to use the old Instant Client 12.2 image on Docker Store, but to use a newer [Instant Client 19 Dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/19/Dockerfile).  It will provision an image without you needing to login or do a click through.  It will let tools connect to Oracle DB 11.2 or later, which is the same as the Docker Store image of 12.2 will connect to.